# Playframework 2, Websockets and Session

Tags: session, websocket, playframework-2.0, session-cookies

I understand that when dealing with websockets, I can't use session.  The playframework 2 websocket chat example adds the username into the url, but what if I have a user thats already loged in and I don't want to pass his username through the url, is there another way to get the users login credentials from within a websocket request?

Here is what I have tried so far:
Request Page from where I will connect to the socket:

```
public static Result index(){
    session("username", "mike")
    return ok(indexpage.render());
}
```

Here is the Websocket part:

```
public static Websocket<JsonNode> chat(){
    System.out.println(session("username"));    
    ....all the websocket stuff
}
```

All that I get printed out is a null
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the session:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index()).withSession("connected" -> "user@gmail.com")
  }

  //I used for views.html.index the html markup from http://www.websocket.org/echo.html
  def wstest = WebSocket.using[String] { request =>

    val in = Iteratee.consume[String]()

    val username = request.session.get("connected").getOrElse("missing username")

    val out = Enumerator("Hello " + username) //puts  Hello user@gmail.com on the screen

    (in, out)
  }
}
```

Ok, now for Java (Methods in a Controller):

```
public static WebSocket<String> chat(){
    final Http.Session session = session();
    final String name = session("username");//better version

    return new WebSocket<String>() {
        public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out) {
            in.onMessage(new F.Callback<String>() {
                public void invoke(String event) {
                    System.out.println(event);
                }
            });

            in.onClose(new F.Callback0() {
                public void invoke() {
                    System.out.println("Disconnected");
                }
            });

            out.write("Hello " + session.get("username"));
            out.write("Hello " + name);
        }
    };
}
```

It seems you cannot access directly the http context in a websocket creation, but you can store the session or better data from the cookies in a constant and use that in the WebSocket instance creation.

I uploaded a Java example with a test https://github.com/schleichardt/stackoverflow-answers/tree/so12879547 (it is not on the master branch).

PS:
that didn't worked in the WebSocket creation:

```
Http.Context.current().session().get("username")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately im using java, forgot to mention that.  Here is what I have tried so far, can't add code to comment, Ill make a reply

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, added the "final Http.Session session = session()", but i still get null when I try to pull out the username from the session.  Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: And if you try 'final String name = session("username");' before Constructing the WebSocket? Are you sure, that you really stored the name into the session? Google Chrome can show you your Cookies. Can you post your project or a minimal example on github?

Comment: Did 'final String name = session("username"); return new WebSocket<String>() {... Logger.info(name) ...' work for you Mike?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i got stuck on another project.  I have checked the code, still doesn't work.  But right now im looking at play 2.1, maybe in the latest version it will be easier

Comment: I added a Java example with a test, try this, please.

Answer (score 1):

The websocket connection is not Http. The first handshake request looks a bit like http, but does contain other fields. That's why you cannot add your http cookie in the websocket request.

From Wikipedia:

> The handshake resembles HTTP so that servers can handle HTTP
>   connections as well as WebSocket connections on the same port. However
>   the specific fields involved, and what follows after the handshake, do
>   not conform to the HTTP protocol.

You can either use a token / session id in the url if you don't want the username there, or then, if you can't implement login/pw retrieval before starting the websocket connection, implement your own method of login/password retrieval through the websocket communication (e.g. server asks for login/pw in a specific format, and the client js reacts, collects it and sends it back to the server).

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to access Session as it is initialized as HTTP handshake.
You can define your username key, value from authenticated action by sticking it to the session:

```
Redirect(.....).withSession("login" -> user)
```

And then:

```
object WebsocketController extends Controller {

  def wsConnection = WebSocket.async[JsValue] { request =>

    val userOption: Option[String] = request.session.get("login")

    //do your credential check or login ....

    (in, out)
  }

}
```

This is indeed secured by playframework